# What is the unit of the y-axis when using distplot to plot a histogram?

Tags: python, seaborn

What is the unit of the y-axis when using distplot to plot a histogram? I have plotted different histograms together with a normal fit and I see that in one case, it has a range of 0 to 0.9 while in another a range of 0 to 4.5.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From `help(sns.distplot)`:

> `norm_hist`: bool, otional
>           If True, the histogram height shows a density rather than a count.
>           This is implied if a KDE or fitted density is plotted.

A *density* is scaled so that the area under the curve is 1, so no individual bin will ever be taller than 1 (the whole dataset). But `kde` is `True` by default and overrides `norm_hist`, so `norm_hist` changes the y-units only if you explicitly set `kde` to `False`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6), ncols=2, nrows=2)
data = np.random.randint(0,20,40)

for row in (0,1):
    for col in (0,1):
        sns.distplot(data, kde=row, norm_hist=col, ax=axs[row, col])

axs[0,0].set_ylabel('NO kernel density')
axs[1,0].set_ylabel('KDE on')
axs[1,0].set_xlabel('norm_hist=False')
axs[1,1].set_xlabel('norm_hist=True')
```

[image]

Comment: This is helpful but I think it would be good to make explicit the idea that a density is scaled so that the area under the curve is 1.

Comment: No problem, Harry. Check it off as done if it answers your question.